# Minimization of convex stochastic values

Tags: matlab, minimize

I have a variable of equidistant values (suppose `values=0:1e-3:1`). I want to get the value and its correspondent index from `values` which is closest to a uniformly random value (suppose `x=rand`).

I could do `[value,vIdx]=min(abs(values-x))`, which would be the simplest minimization I could do. **Unfortunately the `min` function won't take advantage from one property from the data, that is to be convex**. I don't need to search all indexes, because as soon as find an index that is no more lesser than the previous I've found the global minimum. Said that, I don't want to substitute the matlab min function for a loop that would be slower depending on how distant it is from the value I will start. There are many methods that could be used, as the golden section, but I am not sure if using matlab fmincon would be faster than the `min` method.

Does anyone have any hints/ideas how to get the required value faster than using the described `min` method? I'll check the time performance when I have time, but if someone knows a good answer a priori, please let me know.

**Possible Application**: Snap to nearest graphic data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your points are equidistant you can use the value `x` to find the index:

```
vIdx = 1+round(x*(numel(values)-1));
```

The idea is that you are dividing the interval `[0, 1]` into `numel(values)-1` equally sized intervals. Now by multiplying `x` by that number you map the interval to `[0, numel(values)-1]` where your points are mapped to integer values. Now using `round` you get the closest one and by adding 1 you get the one-based index that MATLAB requires.

Comment: Could you update your formula to a more generic one, in the case the values boundaries are not `[0,1]`: `vIdx = 1+round((x-values(1))*(numel(values)-1)/(values(end)-values(1)))`. And thank you for your answer, I think I got so used to iterative methods x(